# Cannot create mock for class LoginService. Mocking of non-interface types requires the CGLIB library..?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I'm using grails 2.4.2 and by default it already has spock installed right? Well, one of my controller tests isn't working quite right. I'm trying to mock several of my services, but I keep getting this error:

```
 Failure:  confirmEmailAddress() when verification failed(com.zee.RegistrationControllerSpec)
|  org.spockframework.mock.CannotCreateMockException: Cannot create mock for class com.zee.LoginService. Mocking of non-interface types requires the CGLIB library. Please put cglib-nodep-2.2 or higher on the class path.
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory.create(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:52)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.JavaMockFactory.create(JavaMockFactory.java:51)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.CompositeMockFactory.create(CompositeMockFactory.java:44)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMock(SpecInternals.java:47)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMockImpl(SpecInternals.java:282)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.MockImpl(SpecInternals.java:83)
    at com.zee.RegistrationControllerSpec.setup(RegistrationControllerSpec.groovy:22)
```

I couldn't really find anything on the internet about this. My controllerSpec looks like this:

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(RegistrationController)
class RegistrationControllerSpec extends Specification {

    LoginService loginService

    EmailAddressConfirmationService emailAddressConfirmationService

    EmailNotificationService emailNotificationService

    AccountRecordService accountRecordService

    def setup() {
        loginService = Mock()
        emailAddressConfirmationService = Mock()
        emailNotificationService = Mock()
        accountRecordService = Mock()

        controller.loginService = loginService
        controller.emailAddressConfirmationService = emailAddressConfirmationService
        controller.emailNotificationService = emailNotificationService
        controller.accountRecordService = accountRecordService
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "confirmEmailAddress() when verification failed"() {
        // some test here....
    }
}
```

My Service is even simpler:

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional
class LoginService {

    def registerUser(Login login) {
        login.pincode = "";
        login.groupId = Login.REGISTERED_USER_GROUP_ID
        login.save(flush :true)
    }

    public void userJoined(Login login) {
        login.save(flush: true)
    }
}
```

I am stomped. Even a grails clean wouldn't do the trick.. Any help? D:

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your `buildConfig.groovy`,
Replace this line:
`':cache:1.1.7'` with `':cache:1.1.6'`
Like so:

```
plugins {
         compile ':cache:1.1.6'
}
```

Turns out that the cglib dependency was removed from the cache plugin. [source](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11535).

edit:
If you still want to use `cache:1.1.7` you can just add the cglib dependency in your `buildConfig.groovy` like this:

```
dependencies { 
        compile 'org.objenesis:objenesis:1.4'
        compile "cglib:cglib:2.2"
}
plugins {
             compile ':cache:1.1.7'
}
```